# How can I skip authentication in a Django APIRequestFactory call?

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-unittest, django-rest-viewsets

So essentially I want to make a request to a ViewSet without requiring to authenticate, does Django APIRequestFactory make this possible? This works:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from .views.SomeViewSet
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory


class ViewSetsTest(TestCase):
    ...
    ...
    ...
    def test_db_instance_viewset(self):
        api_request = APIRequestFactory.patch("", HTTP_AUTHORIZATION="Bearer xyz123ppouu")
        detail_view = SomeViewSet.as_view({'patch': 'update'})
        response = detail_view(api_request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

But the issue is, the bearer token is something that is generated 'somewhere far' every 24 hours. Hence, I want to skip authentication.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [forcing authentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#forcing-authentication)